# Thinking Sphinx can't sort when using delta indexing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm not sure who is at fault here, but we have a column in our users table called last_logged_in_at that we use for sorting. This is in a Rails 2.3 project using Thinking Sphinx with delta indexes enabled.

When a record has delta set to true, it is push to the bottom even if the sorting by last_logged_in_at should put it at the top.

I tried with last_logged_in_at being a datetime, a timestamp and even an integer and the behavior is always the same.

Any ideas why?

The query looks something like:

```
{:populate=>true,
 :match_mode=>:boolean,
 :order=>"last_logged_in_at DESC, updated_at DESC",
 :per_page=>20,
 :with_all=>{:role_id=>17, 
             :state=>"activated",
             :mandator_id=>9,
             :profile_active=>true},
 :page=>nil}
```

Comment: Can you share the search query you're using that's not working?

Comment: @pat there, I added the query.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, life's crazy busy, hence slow reply.

You're filtering on a string - which Sphinx doesn't currently allow. There are [ways around this](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/common_issues.html#string_filters), though.

Also: You're using `:with_all`, but `:with` behaves in exactly the same way in your situation. `:with_all` is useful when you want to match multiple values on a single attribute. For example, this query will match results where articles have **any** of the given tag ids:

```
Article.search :with => {:tag_ids => [1, 2, 3]}
```

But this next query matches articles with **all** of the given tag ids:

```
Article.search :with_all => {:tag_ids => [1, 2, 3]}
```

I realise neither of these points are directly related to your issue - however, it's best to get the query valid first, and then double-check whether the behaviour is correct or not.